# python tuple of tuple extraction

Tags: python, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

Suppose you have the following tuple of tuple:

```
test = ((1, '2'), (3, '4'), ('5', '6'))
```

If I want to extract the second element of each tuple, I would do:

```
secondonly = tuple([x[-1] for x in test])
```

I've also seen:

`secondonly = tuple([x for word, x in test])` <---- ****** <--- how does that work?

Can somebody explain me how the line with ****** is giving the good result? thanks

Comment: `word, x = (1, '2')`, it's simple assignment.

Comment: Also called tuple/list/sequence unpacking http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html .

Comment: Maybe the convention of using `_` for unneeded values will help with the readability: `secondonly = tuple([x for _, x in test])`

Comment: Also, the square brackets are unnecessary here.  `tuple(x for word, x in test)` will work just the same as, if not better than, `tuple([x for word, x in test])`.

Answer (score 3):

*test* contains 3 tuples of length 2. `for word, x in test` (which is equivalent to `for (word, x) in test`) unpacks the first  element of every tuple as *word* and the second as *x*. Thus `[x for (word, x) in test]` takes every second element (*x*) to create a list.

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to what you're doing in the first example - "x for x in blah" builds a list of all the xs accumulated in the for loop. In the example, the for loop includes the assignment of each element of "test" to "word, x", which automatically unpacks the tuple into those two variables and so means "word" and "x" take the first and second elements of each tuple respectively. This means "x" always refers to the second element of the tuple, and so the loop builds up a list of second elements as needed.